# Considerations of model definitions when moving from Tensorflow to PyTorch

Tags: python, tensorflow, pytorch

I've just recently switched to PyTorch after getting frustrated in debugging tf and understand that it is equivalent to coding in numpy almost completely. My question is what are the permitted python aspects we can use in a PyTorch model (to be put completely on GPU) eg. if-else has to be implemented as follows in tensorflow

```
a = tf.Variable([1,2,3,4,5], dtype=tf.float32)
b = tf.Variable([6,7,8,9,10], dtype=tf.float32)
p = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32)
ps = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.bool)

li = [None]*5
li_switch = [True, False, False, True, True]

for i in range(5):
    li[i] = tf.Variable(tf.random.normal([5]))

sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

def func_0():
    return tf.add(a, p)
def func_1():
    return tf.subtract(b, p)

with tf.device('GPU:0'):
    my_op = tf.cond(ps, func_1, func_0)

for i in range(5):
    print(sess.run(my_op, feed_dict={p:li[i], ps:li_switch[i]}))
```

How would the structure change in pytorch for the above code? How to place the variables and ops above on GPU and parallelize the list inputs to our graph in pytorch?

Comment: Could you please provide [A **M**inimal, **C**omplete, and **V**erifiable **E**xample (MCVE)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I do not think every question will follow a template as stack asks us to do. The question is simple, in the pytorch 'model' to be put on GPU, what code will be python (if any) and what will be that of torch? The above code is pretty much what I want. There's some scope for interpretation above and any will help me with a few more words.

Comment: You're correct. But, for us to guarantee you the exact refactoring results. We need to see an example for the input and output, that's not much, I think.

Comment: Okay, I'll edit in some time.

Comment: @AndrewNaguib Let me know

Comment: Your code returns a `ValueError` in Tensorflow, you're aware of that?

Comment: You get the gist right. I haven't run it. There must be some small mistake. It would be completely changed on PyTorch. It's just a demonstration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In pytorch, the code can be written like the way normal python code is written.

**CPU**

```
import torch
a = torch.FloatTensor([1,2,3,4,5])
b = torch.FloatTensor([6,7,8,9,10])
cond = torch.randn(5)

for ci in cond:
    if ci > 0:
        print(torch.add(a, 1))
    else:
        print(torch.sub(b, 1))
```

**GPU**

Move the tensors to GPU like this:

```
a = torch.FloatTensor([1,2,3,4,5]).to('cuda')
b = torch.FloatTensor([6,7,8,9,10]).to('cuda')
cond = torch.randn(5).to('cuda')

import torch.nn as nn

class Cond(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Cond, self).__init__()

    def forward(self, cond, a, b):
        result =  torch.empty(cond.shape[0], a.shape[0]).cuda()
        for i, ci in enumerate(cond):
            if ci > 0:
                result[i] = torch.add(a, 1)
            else:
                result[i] = torch.sub(b, 1)

        return result

cond_model = Cond().to('cuda')
output = cond_model(cond, a, b)
```

https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/blitz/tensor_tutorial.html#cuda-tensors

Comment: No, ci in this case is a parallel input. I guess in your code, for loop runs on CPU and sequentially, and the torch.add() runs on GPU. I want if else to be on the GPU too (inside the model). And the lists are feeded above sequentially but they can be applied parallely too, and for that case complete model needs to be an op graph.
@ManojMohan

Comment: Yes, if we have a model that takes this data, then the model could be moved to the GPU similar to the tensors.

Comment: can you please edit the above code and write it as if else inside model, taking the above 2 lists of 5 elements that run parallely on GPU. It would help me a lot. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

To initialize your `a` and `b` tensors in PyTorch, you do the following:

```
a = torch.tensor([1,2,3,4,5], dtype=torch.float32)
b = torch.tensor([6,7,8,9,10], dtype=torch.float32)
```

**But**, since you need them to be completely on the GPU, you have to use the magic `.cuda()` function. So, it would be:

```
a = torch.tensor([1,2,3,4,5], dtype=torch.float32).cuda()
b = torch.tensor([6,7,8,9,10], dtype=torch.float32).cuda()
```

Which moves the tensor to the GPU

---

Another way of initializing is:

```
a = torch.FloatTensor([1,2,3,4,5]).cuda()
b = torch.FloatTensor([6,7,8,9,10]).cuda()
```

---

If we need to generate a random normal distribution we use [`torch.randn`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torch.html#torch.randn) (there is also [`torch.rand`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torch.html#torch.rand) which does a uniform random distribution).

```
li = torch.randn(5, 5)
```

(Catch the bug, it has to be initialized on `cuda`, you cannot do operations on tensors that are located on separate processing units, i.e., CPU and GPU)

```
li = torch.randn(5, 5).cuda()
```

*There is no difference for the `li_switch` initialization.*

One possible way of handling your `func_0` and `func_1` is to declare them as

```
def func_0(li_value):
    return torch.add(a, li_value)
def func_1(li_value):
    return torch.sub(b, li_value)
```

Then, for the predicate function call, it could be as simple as doing this:

```
for i, pred in enumerate(li_switch):
    if pred:
        func_0(li[i])
    else:
        func_1(li[i])
```

---

However, I suggest vectorizing your operations and do something like:

```
li_switch = torch.tensor([True, False, False, True, True])
torch.add(a, li[li_switch]).sum(dim=0)
torch.sub(b, li[~li_switch]).sum(dim=0)
```

This is much more optimized.

Comment: Yes, it will run sequentially.

Comment: That's what I don't want. I want that to be inside the model and run 100 if elses parallely on GPU. tf.cond is a computational graph op which can be placed on GPU.

Comment: Don't be so literal Andrew, remove the disclaimer, understand the intention.

Comment: Hmm, okay, I removed it :)

Comment: @caissalover Check the new update and tell if that fits with you.